# Hikers in Halloween

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, rhyme, poetry, acronym

### HAPPY HALLOWEEN!

> Hello, it's me, again today,
>
> With some new clues for us to play.
>
> When hikers go hiking during Halloween,
>
> There's always a cool thing, a little green.
>
> So here are some letter for you to know,
>
> And sit back, relax, and enjoy the show.

- MDGOT
- YHTSMTMM
- APSIAPE
- YGWYPF
- YGAPMAFAYFHFADYTHTFAYGHAOTWFHFAL

---

What is the answer?

---

Hints:

- > Only the fourth line of the poem is helpful. The rest is fluff/herring.
- > Look at the tags!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Partial answer**

The nonsense characters are

> initial letters of the following sayings: "Money doesn't grow on trees", "You have to spend money to save money", "A penny saved is a penny earned", "You get what you pay for", and "You give a poor man a fish and you feed him for a day; you teach him to fish and you give him an occupation that will feed him for a lifetime".

(Note: I didn't look at AHKieran's answer.)

The connection to Halloween or hiking isn't obvious to me, though.

> Something to do with not giving sweets to trick-or-treating children? Some connection with "money is the root of all *evil*"? The "*spectre* haunting Europe" at the start of the Communist Manifesto?! These all seem very unsatisfactory indeed.

MOehm points out in comments that

> the 31st of October is not only Halloween but also something called World Savings Day, a thing promoted by banks, especially in less-wealthy countries. That seems relevant though it's not clear how it leads to an actual *answer*.

Maybe the answer is just

> *money* (which I suppose you could describe as "a little green" in reference to the traditional colour of dollar bills, though that line is allegedly just fluff).

Comment: rot13(Znlor "Uvxref Tb Uvxvat" vf zrnag gb znc gb "Unir n Terng Unyybjrra"?)

Comment: I ... guess? How would that help us get an answer from what we know so far, though?

Comment: 31 Oct is [a special day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Savings_Day) to friends of the mentioned sayings. (But I can't really see how this contributes to the answer.)

Comment: Hmm, that does seem extremely relevant.

Comment: Soorryyy, I meant fourth line... This is correct

Answer (score 3):

As given by the tags:

> The letters are acronyms. And they appear to be famous sayings.

Partial Answers:

MDGOT

> 

YHTSMTMM

> You Have To See Me To ??

APSIAPE

> A Penny Saved Is A Penny Earned

YGWYPF

> You Get What You Pay For

YGAPMAFAYFHFADYTHTFAYGHAOTWFHFAL

> 